# Python3 - Leetcode Question sample usecase is failing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this Leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/design-browser-history/

Below is my code:

```
class BrowserHistory:

    def __init__(self, homepage: str):
        self.history = []
        self.history.append(homepage)  
        self.currPos = 0

    def visit(self, url: str) -> None:
        self.history.append(url)
        self.currPos = len(self.history) - 1

    def back(self, steps: int) -> str:
        pos = self.currPos - steps
        if pos <= 0:
            self.currPos = 0
            return self.history[0]
        else:
            self.currPos = pos
            return self.history[pos]

    def forward(self, steps: int) -> str:
        pos2 = self.currPos + steps
        if pos2 >= len(self.history) - 1:
            self.currPos = len(self.history) - 1
            return self.history[-1]
        else:
            self.currPos = pos2
            return self.history[pos2]
```

When I run this, the sample usecase is failing:

```
INPUT:
["BrowserHistory","visit","visit","visit","back","back","forward","visit","forward","back","back"]

[["leetcode.com"],["google.com"],["facebook.com"],["youtube.com"],[1],[1],[1],["linkedin.com"],[2],[2],[7]]

OUTPUT:
[null,null,null,null,"facebook.com","google.com","facebook.com",null,"linkedin.com","facebook.com","leetcode.com"]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
[null,null,null,null,"facebook.com","google.com","facebook.com",null,"linkedin.com","google.com","leetcode.com"]
```

Not sure why back of 2 steps should give google.com instead of facebook.com.

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Remember that the history after your current point is **replaced** when you "visit". It is not **appended**. Youtube is removed from the stack when you go to linkedin.

Comment: I couldn't figure that part out. let me try it with that :)

Comment: I spelled it out with diagrams and everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you visit a site, you expect that going back will take you to the site you came from, not the site at the end of your stack.

Let's say that you have the following history:

```
google.com -> facebook.com -> youtube.com
                                  ^
                             You are here
```

You then decide to go back to `facebook.com`:

```
google.com -> facebook.com -> youtube.com
                  ^
             You are here
```

When you go forward, you expect to be back to `youtube.com`. So far so good.

But what if you want to go and visit `linkedin.com` from here? Currently your code is appending to the stack:

```
google.com -> facebook.com -> youtube.com -> linkedin.com
                                                  ^
                                             You are here
```

That structure says that going back one will take you to `youtube.com`, even though that's incorrect: you came from `facebook.com`.

So the solution is not just to append: you have to truncate first:

```
google.com -> facebook.com -> linkedin.com
                                   ^
                              You are here
```

Specifically, rather than updating `currPos` from the length, update the length to match `currPos`:

```
def visit(self, url: str) -> None:
    self.currPos += 1
    del self.history[currPos:]
    self.history.append(url)
```